Is it possible to create meshes and modulate it wit waves?
To be honest it's very difficult to explain what I'm asking.
So I show you here a reference picture;
I would like to recreate this kind of mesh and modulate it with waves
NOTE: I have created a mesh (grid) but I don't find the way to "wavy" it
NOTE 2: I'm really noob in Blender.
EDIT: I edit this to thank ppl tried to help me, although I recon to have missed an information: I need to place the curves (waves ?) exactly in the position and height I need.
So they shouldn't be randomly generated


What is the format of the height data you have?

After your edit of your question, I'll try and answer with some more insights.
Both answers by @Daniel Möller (answer) and @moonboots (answer) can still be used, but instead of using any noise map, use an image as your height map instead.
Another route is to use Proportional Editing to easily make smooth mounds and dents in your plane.
The same could be achieved with Sculpting, but Proportional Editing is most likely easier, in this case.
Just enable Proportional Editing at the top of the viewport, and set it to Smooth.

Then select your vertex/vertices, press G to move them (and then the axis, if you want to them them on one axis only), and use your scrollwheel to change the size of the influence of Proportional Editing.


This is working perfectly. However, how can I use an an image as height map, please?  I'm not aware about this.

Instead of using a procedural texture in the Legacy Texture, you choose Image or Movie, then select your image.

So far I understand, it's a BW image where the black an white are top/bottom peaks, while grays are intermediate regions? And by importing them the way you suggested, Blender applies this o the vertical axis of the grid?

@TormyVanCool That's it, yes.

Take a well subdivided plane and add a noise texture in geometry nodes.
There is a LOT of flexibility for making many types of waves:
Hints:

Use 2D noise
Multiply by a tiny value to scale the height of the waves
Set the noise as the Z component of an offset to the geometry

Below are two examples using different configs in the noise texture.



thank you for your suggestion. I edited my post because reading the suggestions here I recognized I missed an information. So I added it into the main post.

Create a plane, subdivide it, give it a Displace modifier, click on the Show Texture button and in the Texture panel choose a Type > Clouds texture, set its Size, then back into the modifier panel, give it a Wireframe modifier to create the net, set the Thickness:


thank you for your suggestion. I edited my post because reading the suggestions here I recognized I missed an information. So I added it into the main post.
